# How to make cloudfront https calls to origin in http

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have the origin http://app.mydomain.com/v2/check (no https)

I have configured my cloudfront with ssl cert *.mydomain.com

In Route53 I have created A record with alias app2.mydomain.com pointing to Cloudfront  xyz.cloudfront.net

Now how to I set behavior such that I call (POST) https://app2.mydomain.com/v2/check it call http://app.mydomain.com:8081/v2/check.

curl command
Working

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://app.mydomain.com/v2/check' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'disabledRules=WHITESPACE_RULE' \
--data-urlencode 'text="The quick read focks jumped over the lazy broon dogg."' \
--data-urlencode 'language=en-US'
```

not working getting http 403 error

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://app2.mydomain.com/v2/check' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'disabledRules=WHITESPACE_RULE' \
--data-urlencode 'text="The quick read focks jumped over the lazy broon dogg."' \
--data-urlencode 'language=en-US'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by by modifying the origin.

**In the console:**

- Select the `Origin and Origin Groups` tab.
- Select the Origin and click `Edit`
- Once you click edit there is an option for Origin Protocol Policy. Select the value of `HTTP Only` as shown below in the screenshot.
- Click `Yes/Edit`

[image]

This can be performed in the CLI by performing the [update-distribution](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html) function, or in CloudFormation by updating the [OriginProtocolPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-customoriginconfig.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-customoriginconfig-originprotocolpolicy) value to `http-only`.

As you're using `POST` requests ensure that it is enabled in the `Allowed HTTP Methods` within the Behaviour for the origin. This returns a 403 if the method  is not enabled.

[image].

Other than this ensure the host that you're trying to connect to through either the browser or programmatically as an API call, is added as an alternative domain name in the CloudFront Distribution configuration.

Comment: I had tried this suggestion I am getting erro 403. Also I have updated with more details that the origin needs to 8081. Do I need an origin path?

Comment: Hmm so I can see from your screenshot you have http path,  is your app accessible in the browser using the http domain and port? And are you forwarding the correct host header?

Comment: yes it is accessable using http domain and port. I have given the curl command I am using above. Can you elaborate what you mean by forwarding the correct host header. Is it a cloudfront setting.

Comment: I just noticed you're adding post requests, have you enabled post requests in your CloudFront distribution. This would be under the `Allowed HTTP Methods` when editing the behaviour. If this is set are you seeing the requests come through from CloudFront?

Comment: yes had been done also. I updated above also with that information

Comment: Can you see incoming requests on your server?

Comment: when using app2.mydomain.com it is not reaching the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218070/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

In the Alternate Domain Names CNAME section I had to put **app2.domain.com** in the list. I had only domain.com do to which it was not working.